# Long List Selector do not refresh object placed in a specific position

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

`LongListSelector` do not refresh object placed in a specific position(after updating that object), but refreshes all other objects.

Like, when there is only one object in `LLS`, the only object is not refreshed(and  definitely converter used in that object is not called), similarly when there are three objects in `LLS`, the 2nd one is not refreshed(and  definitely converter used in that object is not called).

Likewise when there are 5 objects the 3rd one is not refreshed and so on. But, when there are even number of objects, all objects are refreshed correctly. I used Converter in `DataTemplate` due to which I found this problem.

By placing break point in converter, I analysed that when I come back to the `LLS` page(after updating an object) the converter is called one less times the total number of objects(when there are odd number of objects in `LLS`). I don't know why this is happening? my code for all objects is same. Is it the `LongList` Problem or some thing else?

Note: by "Not Refreshing" I mean Not updating the user interface.

My [Problem Project is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/88rufy6afvtn7ug/LongListSelectorTest%28UpdationProblem%29%281%29.rar) Please check this running project.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Now I've looked through your code and I can see that you use a `List` as the `ItemsSource`.  You need to use an `ObservableCollection`.